# 2 inline images - 1 centered and 1 right using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using center-block on the centered image forces the 2nd image to drop below: - what is best practice to position 2 elements like this? I'm thinking I could divide the header into 3 columns and pull the 2nd image right within the 3rd.

```
<header class="" id="top" role="banner">
<div class="container" >
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

<img src="<?php echo $folder;?>img/header.png" alt="" class="center-block"/>
<img src="<?php echo $folder;?>img/main_logo.png" alt="" class="pull-right" />


</nav>  
</div>
<hr>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `display: inline-block;` for images, and `text-align: center;` for parent. Second image gets `float: right;` . Note the first image will be centered in space between left border and the second image, if that's something you're aiming to do.

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
}

nav img {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav img + img {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9Lave1x/2/

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I was hoping the centre the first image in the Nav, regardless of 2 image position and size.

Comment: oh, then change css for second image to : `position:absolute; right:0;` http://jsfiddle.net/a9Lave1x/5/